# 'user' is always nil in logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions in Parse iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using Facebook SDK with Parse SDK in user Login.
Using '`logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions`' to perform login, Even though user is authenticated the app, 'user' is always nil in the response. And error is:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.login Code=304 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.login error 304.)"

Here is my Implementation:

**• Basic configuration:** 
I have configured every thing in `.plist`
and followed guidelines at [link1](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users), [link2](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/wiki/Integrate-Login-with-Facebook)

**• Imported frameworks:**

[image]

**• Implementation in Appdelegate:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"I have used real key here" clientKey:@"I have used real key here"];
    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    return YES; }
```

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

**• Login Implementation:**

```
NSArray *fbPermissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"public_profile", nil];
    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:fbPermissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        }
        else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
        }
    }];
```

But in the call back, 'user' is always nil. Did anyone face the same issue?
- Thanks in advance.

Comment: I checked out the two links. Did you also follow face book's app creation tutorial?

Comment: Is the Facebook user that you're trying to log in with registered in the Facebook developer app's `roles`? You must log in with either the account that created the app, or have to log in with an account that is authorized in the `roles` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find out cause for the issue. But I just deleted all frameworks related to Parse and Facebook and Re-added all of them. It worked fine. So, there is no issue in the code.

Answer (score 0):

in `AppDelegate.m` file, under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, initialize Parse before initializing `PFFacebookUtils`.